# Use scrollTop with a specific div

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I, I've a website with a fixed logo on the left top corner (the logo is total white).
There is a certain point of the homepage with an about div with white background.
I need the the logo change with the black version when the about div go over the logo.

I tried to use the scrollTop function with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
            //function that change the logo
        }
     });
});
```

Anyway with that code the function works when there are 1000px form margin top.
I need it works when i scroll to that div.
Any ideas?

/*** UPDATE ***/
I fixed the code by my own, hope this can help other people.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var divTeam = $('#team').offset().top;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > divTeam) {
        $('.logo_small').attr("src", "img/logo_small_dark.png");
        $('.nav_icon').attr("src", "img/nav_icon_dark.png");
    }
    else { 
        $('.logo_small').attr("src", "img/logo_small.png");
        $('.nav_icon').attr("src", "img/nav_icon.png");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What did you change? It doesn't work yet.